# storing a three.js mesh object with indexedDB

Tags: javascript, three.js, indexeddb

Utilising [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IndexedDB_primer) I'm trying to see if I can save bandwidth with a large mesh by caching it with indexedDB.

So inside the loader callback function I'm doing...

```
object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

webkitIndexedDB.open("MyNewDB").onsuccess = function(event) {
  window.db = event.srcElement.result;

  window.db.setVersion("1.0").onsuccess = function(event) {
    var objectStore = window.db.createObjectStore("meshes", { keyPath: "item_id" });

    objectStore.add({item_id: 0, mesh: object});  //  <= this is the crucial line

  };
};
```

however the last line where an object containing `object` is added to the database causes the following error.

`Uncaught Error: DATA_CLONE_ERR: DOM Exception 25`

I'm not sure what this really means but there must be a way around it no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your `THREE.Mesh` `object` is malformed, but not in a way that's violating indexes, uniqueness, or anything like that. I see this error when I try to store objects that have un-executed functions as members.

The technical definition from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBObjectStore-put) is:

> The data being stored could not be cloned by the internal structured
>   cloning algorithm.

If you're trying to store object state of a namespace you're hosed. If you're storing plain data I would try doing a deep copy of the THREE.Mesh() object checking `typeof` for 'function.'

EDIT: I looked into this further. IndexedDB copies objects into the object store using the HTML5 [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm). According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/), Error and Function objects cannot be cloned and throw a `DATA_CLONE_ERR`. That's what you're seeing.